# Find tables, columns with specific value

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm using Firebird 2.5.0. I know a value and need to find all tables, columns in which it occurs. 

I created procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE NEW_PROCEDURE (
    searching_value varchar(30))
returns (
    table_with_value varchar(100),
    column_with_value varchar(100))
as 
declare variable all_tables varchar(50);
declare variable all_columns varchar(50);
declare variable all_values varchar(50);
begin
    FOR SELECT
        r.rdb$relation_name, f.rdb$field_name
        from rdb$relation_fields f
        join rdb$relations r on f.rdb$relation_name = r.rdb$relation_name
        and r.rdb$view_blr is null 
        and (r.rdb$system_flag is null or r.rdb$system_flag = 0)
        order by 1, f.rdb$field_position INTO :all_tables, :all_columns
    DO
    BEGIN
        FOR SELECT all_columns FROM all_tables
            INTO :all_Values
        DO
        BEGIN
            IF (SEARCHING_VALUE = all_Values) THEN
            BEGIN
                table_With_Value = all_Tables;
                column_With_Value = all_Columns;
                SUSPEND;
            END
        END
    END
END^
```

When I run it I get error message:

Undefined name.

Dynamic SQL Error.

SQL error code = -204.

Table unknown.

ALL_TABLES.

At line 21, column 13.


 So in this select statement "SELECT all_columns FROM all_tables" it is not taking values from previous for select statement but just trying to find table all_tables. How to fix it?

Comment: I didn't checked the statement but you can't read data from all_tables because firebird will search for a table named all_tables. Use execute statement to fetch the data.   http://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.EXECUTESTATEMENTFB2

Comment: You can't parametrize table names like that, you would need to use `EXECUTE STATEMENT` with a dynamically constructed query instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `all_columns` is considered to be a colum name and `all_tables` a table name and not your variables in:

```
SELECT all_columns FROM all_tables
```

You can't parametrize objectnames in a query like this. Also note that if it had been possible to parametrize object names, you would have had to use `:all_columns` and `:all_tables` for disambiguation.

Instead you will need to create a dynamic SQL statement and execute that with [`EXECUTE STATEMENT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt) (or more specifically: [`FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-forexec)).

In this case:

```
FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT 'SELECT "' || all_columns || '" FROM "' || all_tables || '"'
    INTO :all_values
DO
BEGIN
    /* .... */
END
```

I have quoted the object names to account for case sensitive column and table names (or identifiers that are invalid unquoted). Constructing a query like this might leave you open to SQL injection if the values are obtained from another source than the Firebird metadata tables.