# How to find a value in all tables on firebird?

Tags: sql, search, firebird

How to search for a value in all tables on Firebird?

Knowing a value, I need to find all tables, columns in which it occurs.
Someone can help me please? I have no clue where to start.

I'm using Firebird 3.0.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do that, you will need to explicitly query all (relevant) columns of all tables to achieve this. Maybe you can take inspiration from this question: [Find tables, columns with specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342993/find-tables-columns-with-specific-value)

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do that, you will need to explicitly query all (relevant) columns of all tables to achieve this. Taking inspiration from the not working code by [kamil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5717483/kamil) in [Find tables, columns with specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342993/find-tables-columns-with-specific-value), you could do something like:

```sql
execute block
returns (
    table_name varchar(63),
    column_name varchar(63))
as 
declare search_value varchar(30) = 'John';
declare has_result boolean;
begin
    for select trim(r.rdb$relation_name), trim(f.rdb$field_name)
        from rdb$relation_fields f
        join rdb$relations r on f.rdb$relation_name = r.rdb$relation_name
        and r.rdb$view_blr is null 
        and (r.rdb$system_flag is null or r.rdb$system_flag = 0)
        order by r.rdb$relation_name, f.rdb$field_position 
        into :table_name, :column_name
    do
    begin
        execute statement ('select exists(select * from "' || table_name || '" where "' || column_name || '" = ?) from rdb$database') (search_value) 
            into has_result;
        if (has_result) then
            suspend;
        when any do
        begin 
            /* value not comparable with varchar, skip */
        end
    end
end
```

This identifies which table + column is equal to `search_value` (but you can of course use a different condition than `=`, e.g. `containing ?` if you want to check for columns that contain `search_value`).

The above could be further refined by only selecting columns of an appropriate type, etc. And of course, the `varchar(30)` might not be suitable or sufficient for all situations.

You could also change this to a stored procedure, e.g. by changing the header to

```sql
create procedure search_all(search_value varchar(30))
returns (
    table_name varchar(63),
    column_name varchar(63))
as 
declare has_result boolean;
begin
  -- ... rest of code above
```

You can then execute it with:

```sql
select * from search_all('John')
```

Comment: Can a declared value be used in the Output?
 I added a row with an SQL Statement that helps to dig deeper: `for select trim(r.rdb$relation_name), trim(f.rdb$field_name), 'select * from ' || trim(r.rdb$relation_name) || ' where ' || trim(f.rdb$field_name) || ' like ' || '''search_value'' ` I was not able to reference the declares, so for now i added just a fixed string... (PS: Only SELECT's are allowed where i use this, so a stored procedure is not an option.)

Comment: Also, i failed to define the declares via parameters so i get prompted for them. I tried a few things like `declare search_value varchar(30) = :search_value;` (not sure about the correct terminology... parameters? variables?)

Comment: @sirtet `for select` only exists in PSQL. So if you can't even execute an `execute block`, then you cannot use it at all.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, that's a misunderstanding. I can execute the full sql above. But  I can't create a stored procedure etc. I think I am basically restricted to read only operations.

Comment: @sirtet There is no `for select` in plain DSQL (except inside an `execute block`), so that cannot work. Maybe I don't understand your question. Consider posting a new question, or asking on https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, referencing the declared value is solved, i had to add a colon to access it: ```:search_value```.
For my 2nd issue, i posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77920038/firebird-sql-how-can-i-assign-a-declare-value-interactively